# Is it possible to use NativeScript's WebView as a WebMap in a hybrid app?

Tags: webview, nativescript

For example, the WebView will load a local `map.html`

This `map.html` will have a map loaded on it via `main-page.js`, so this JS file will by both Native and WebView elements.

On top of this WebView map will be a floating native button that pans the map to your location.

Is this flow possible in NativeScript? A JS file that controls both native elements and a WebView

If possible, how is this integration achieved? Does it need some complex setup?

Is this flow recommended? Would it cause any major performance issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's absolutely possible to have a WebView and place native button over it. But you can't control everything within single JS file, you have to use [nativescript-webview-interface](https://github.com/shripalsoni04/nativescript-webview-interface) plugin to interact between WebView and native functions.

If you ask about performance, WebView is never great not just with NativeScript but in general. Imagine how you would feel when using your [Google Maps](http://maps.google.co.in/) within Chrome of your Android, that's going to be the user experience. Almost every map apis got native libraries for iOS & Android, at least {N} has plugins for Google Map and Mapbox, so I would recommend that.

Comment: I understand what I'm trying to achieve is possible in cordova, but there will be no native UI, but if I use a plugin for cordova that adds native UI (like Ace) it should work right? Unfortunately Esri has no cordova plugin and our team doesn't have a mobile developer

Comment: You can always use LeafletJS inside NS WebView too, mainly for a OpenStreetMap experience, custom map layers coming from let's say GeoServer, etc.

Comment: Yes, in that case you should be fine with WebView.